# Javascript new keyword not resetting all properties

Tags: javascript, oop

Look at the code bellow. I would except that the output would be 123-admin 0-null. But instead its 123-admin 0-admin. Can you explain me why the new keyword does not replace the entire user object?

```
function User()
{

}
User.prototype.id=0;
User.prototype.role={name:null}

var user = new User();
user.role.name = 'admin';
user.id = 123;
window.document.write(" "+user.id+"-"+user.role.name);
user = new User();
window.document.write(" "+user.id+"-"+user.role.name);
```

Also in JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/tfgx77au/6/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `role` property is on the prototype, so that object is shared among all instances created with the constructor.

If you wanted a separate `role` object on each user, you'd have to initialize that in the constructor (or somewhere at least):

```
function User() {
  this.role = { name: null };
}
```

Comment: But the id property changes to to 0 after the second new while  the role is not changed. What the difference?

Comment: @NatanRubinstein the difference is that the "id" property is *directly* a property of each `User` instance. The "name" property you're setting is not - it's a property of the (shared) "role" property. The "role" is on the prototype object and therefore shared by all instances.

Comment: @NatanRubinstein when you do an assignment to an object property, like `user.id=123;` that *always* puts the property directly on the object, even if there's already a like-named property on the prototype. To put that another way, you cannot assign to a prototype property *directly* via an instance. However, you *can* assign a value to a property of a shared object on the prototype. It's the last `.` that counts :)